# CSS - hover ul items not in vertical line

Tags: css, hover, html-lists, block, unordered

I'm brand new to `HTML` and `CSS`, and right now I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TU45mMW_xmc&list=PL46OtmPr4deE9gh7V5AKxk_UjhaK6pO2k&index=16) tutorial. My problem [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAJP7.png) is that the items in my drop-down list are not in a vertical line, but all cluttered together.

I'm sure it's a simple problem with a simple solution but I am not making any progress finding one...

I would be so grateful for some suggestions! :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* ----- NAVIGATION BAR ----- */

#nav {
  width:500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: none;
}

#nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}

#nav ul:after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
  background: #76C5CF;
}

#nav ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}

#nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

/* ----- HEADER ----- */

#header {
  width: 340px
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#header h1 {
  height: 50px;
  font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
  background-color:
}

#header h2 {
  font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

/* ----- BACKGROUND ----- */
body {
  background-color: #A6D7F3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Harley's Haunts </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="harleysHaunts.css">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trocchi');
  </style>
</head>

  <body>

      <div id="header">

        <h1> HARLEY'S HAUNTS </h1>
        <h2> It's a dog's world after all </h2>

      </div>

      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Pet-Friendly Venues </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"> Cafes </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#"> Restaurants </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#"> Pubs/Bars </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#"> Shops </a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>


      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using `inline-block` instead of `inline-table`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem. But thank you for the suggestion! It turns out I needed to add "position: relative" under my "#nav ul li { "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add `position:relative` to #nav ul li :

```
#nav ul li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
```

but you should use this only for the li parent and you shouldn't use `float:left` in the li of the ul child.

So your **css** will become like this

```
#nav > ul > li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It worked - hoorah! :D Thank you so much for answering my question so quickly!!

Comment: you are welcome .. if it helped! you can mark it as answer :).

Comment: Done! I had to wait for the 7 minute countdown :P

Comment: I edited my answer .. you can see that the problem was in the float property :D

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific width to `#nav ul ul`, gave it 200px as example considering parent `ul` `width`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* ----- NAVIGATION BAR ----- */

#nav {
  width:500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: none;
}

#nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}

#nav ul:after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
  background: #76C5CF;
}

#nav ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}

#nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

/* ----- HEADER ----- */

#header {
  width: 340px
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#header h1 {
  height: 50px;
  font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
  background-color:
}

#header h2 {
  font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

/* ----- BACKGROUND ----- */
body {
  background-color: #A6D7F3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Harley's Haunts </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="harleysHaunts.css">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trocchi');
  </style>
</head>

  <body>

      <div id="header">

        <h1> HARLEY'S HAUNTS </h1>
        <h2> It's a dog's world after all </h2>

      </div>

      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Pet-Friendly Venues </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"> Cafes </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#"> Restaurants </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#"> Pubs/Bars </a> </li>
              <li><a href="#"> Shops </a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>


      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That also worked! I have two working suggestions now 

1. #nav > ul > li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;

2. Add a specific width to #nav ul ul

Is there any specific benefit to one over the other?

Comment: To be frank they are both 1 line of code modification so it's really up to you :)

Comment: Gotcha ;) Thank you, Syden!

Answer (score 0):

You have applied rules CSS for all children of the ul parent, so all chidren of **ul ul** they will be inherited the rule of parent CSS.

Try to use selector reference '**>**'  when you want to target only parent element

For this exemple you just change

```
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

by

```
#nav > ul >li {
 float: left;
}
```